# Reading CSV into Dict - Works in REPL, Not in Class

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm using read_csv from pandas to read in quite a large file - some may be familiar with - its the urban dictionary words and definitions. I have no problem doing this in the REPL, but when coding it into a class and an actual file, iterating over the "list of dictionaries" and accessing the key by name ... it returns NaN of type *float* see [debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNol1.png)

I have to assume its something with putting it in a class? Maybe I should stick to functions? Anyone help a nub amateur out and clue me in as to what th is going on here? P.S. Rather than take a parameter and read that file in every time, I'm going to just return the dictionary, but this would remain an issue. Here's the code:

```py
def slang(self, term):
        """Attempts to define any given slang words or terms"""
        
        urban = {}
        doc = self.folder + '\\urbandict.csv'
        data = read_csv(doc, on_bad_lines='skip')

        recs = data.to_dict('records')
        for rec in recs:
            urban[rec['word'].lower()] = rec['definition']

        if urban.get(term.lower()) is None:
            messagebox.showinfo(
                title='No Results', message='Search could not find %s' % term)
        else:
            meaning = urban.get(term.lower())
            messagebox.showinfo(title='Definition', message=meaning)
```

P.P.S. The folder  it's mapped to is correct... the file contents reads in fine. And the *.lower()* function isn't the cause, but it *is* referenced in the traceback. Normally, it'd be a string and it'd work fine. Just weird how it works in REPL but not in the file.

Comment: Could it be that maybe some of those rec['word'] have value NaN/float instead. I cannot see the "full picture" of your code, maybe throw an exception for those.

Comment: I'll give that a shot... but for the particular word for which I attempted to **_.get()_** the definition has a value in that key. It also worked fine in a regular Python console like IDLE  using the same word. I thought *"on_bad_lines='skip'* would have taken care of that, though. 

But no one else has answered, so I will try your suggestion. Thank you for replying either way!